# ++i and i+1 passed to function giving different results in c++

Tags: c++, function, operator-overloading

```
#include <stdio.h>
    
int noOfTriplet(int arr[], int n, int product, int count, int m){
    if(count == 3 && product == m) return 1;
    else if(count == 3 || n==0) return 0;
    // using count+1 here gives answer 3 while passing ++count gives answer 1 why
    return noOfTriplet(arr, n-1, product*arr[n-1], count + 1, m) + noOfTriplet(arr, n-1, product, count, m);
}

int main(){
    int arr[] = { 1, 4, 6, 2, 3, 8};
    int n = 6;
    int product = 1;
    int count = 0;
    int m = 24;
    printf("%d\n", noOfTriplet(arr, n, product, count, m));  
}
```

In the above code while passing count +1 answer is 3 but when i write ++count answer becomes 1.
this should not behave like this. As count +1 and ++count are equivalent.

Comment: Who told you `++i` and `i+1` are equivalent? One *modifies* the variable, other does not modify anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In

```
return noOfTriplet(arr, n-1, product*arr[n-1], count + 1, m) + noOfTriplet(arr, n-1, product, count, m);
```

you are using `count` twice. When you are changing to

```
return noOfTriplet(arr, n-1, product*arr[n-1], ++count, m) + noOfTriplet(arr, n-1, product, count, m);
```

then the compiler might evaluate `noOfTriplet(arr, n-1, product*arr[n-1], ++count, m)` first, with the side effect of increasing `count` and then evaluate `noOfTriplet(arr, n-1, product, count, m)` using the already increased `count`. Thus the difference in the result.

Since the order of the evaluation is not defined (yes, these rules changed a bit in C++17, but nevertheless) you should not rely on this and keep the version that you currently have with `count + 1` and `count`.

Answer (score 3):

In your return statement of the function noOfTriplet() you use the `count` variable in 2 recursive calls by adding up their result as follows:

```
return noOfTriplet(arr, n-1, product*arr[n-1], count + 1, m)
       +
       noOfTriplet(arr, n-1, product, count, m);
```

First of all, you can't assume which of those recursive calls will be made first because of the `+` operator, and it depends on the compiler.

Next, you should realize that `count + 1` will not change the actual value of the parameter `count`, while `++count` will certainly do.

Answer (score 1):

The expressions are not the same, `operator ++` changes the variable value, `count + 1` does not, it evaluates the expression and uses its result.

Furthermore, the expression:

```
return noOfTriplet(arr, n-1, product*arr[n-1], ++count, m) + 
noOfTriplet(arr, n-1, product, count, m);
```

Is unsequenced thus resulting in undefined/unspecified behavior.

> *Order of evaluation of any part of any expression, including order of evaluation of function arguments is unspecified. The compiler can evaluate operands and other subexpressions in any order, and may choose another order when the same expression is evaluated again.*

Examples:

> *1) If a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to another side effect on the same scalar object, the behavior is undefined.*

```
i = ++i + 2;       // undefined behavior until C++11
i = i++ + 2;       // undefined behavior until C++17
f(i = -2, i = -2); // undefined behavior until C++17
f(++i, ++i);       // undefined behavior until C++17, unspecified after C++17
i = ++i + i++;     // undefined behavior
```

> *2) If a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to a value computation using the value of the same scalar object, the behavior is undefined.*

```
cout << i << i++; // undefined behavior until C++17
a[i] = i++;       // undefined behavior until C++17
n = ++i + i;      // undefined behavior
```

https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/eval_order

Comment: this ans has more explanations! +1

Comment: Thanks @LernerCpp, it's the nature of SO, normally the first answers get more votes, and in this case they do answer the question, I just felt like adding some more detail to it.